# Validition: variable with limited number of values (enum)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I would like a model variable that either has value 0, 1 or 2. In my migration I have:

```
t.integer :var, null:false, default: '0'
```

And in my model file:

```
enum :var, [ '0', '1', '2' ]
```

However, all tests (also unrelated ones) now produce the error below, referring to the above model line. What have I done wrong?

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't have the `,`, rather write as :

```
enum var: [ '0', '1', '2' ]
```

Please refer the [documentation](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you tried to do, but require receives a single argument. The error wrong number of arguments means that you are trying to call a method with an unexpected number of arguments. (2 for 1) means you are trying to call a method with one argument with two.

You should be using

```
enum var: [ '0', '1', '2' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct syntax is:

```
enum var: [ '0', '1', '2' ]
```